# Wordpress - Get custom taxonomy/category direct children only

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I have the below code which is pulling in all child categories including grand children - how can I edit this so it ONLY pulls in the direct children?

```
 $subCategories = get_term_children( $categoryID, 'product_club' );

$subcategoryData = '[';
if(!empty($subCategories)) {
$isFirst = true;
foreach($subCategories as $subCategory) {
  $term = get_term_by( 'id', $subCategory, 'product_club' );
  if(!$isFirst) $subcategoryData .= ', ';
  $isFirst = false;
  $subcategoryData .= '{"id": '.$term->term_id.', "name": "'.$term->name.'"}';
}
}
$subcategoryData .= ']';
echo $subcategoryData;
die;
```

Big thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May need some adjusting. This will get all direct children of `$categoryID` of taxonomy type 'product_club'.

```
$args = array(
    'child_of' => $categoryID,
    'taxonomy' => 'product_club',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'depth'  => 1,
    );
$cats = get_categories( $args );
```

The magic parameter is 'depth'.

Comment: Fantastic!  Thank you.  This was just about spot on, I just had to add

    'parent' => $categoryID,

to the args to get it to hide the grand-children otherwise they all showed but in a sensible order, unlike before.

Thank you!